# Show Hide Login Div

Tags: javascript

What am I doing wrong here?

```
var icon = documment.getElementById("loginIcon");
var content = documment.getElementById("loginField");
icon.onclick = function() {
if (content.style.visibility==="visible") {
content.style.visibility="hidden";
}
else {
content.style.visibility="visible";
}
}
```

"loginIcon" is an ID I've assigned to a PNG (I put the ID in a div) I made in photoshop. It's displaying fine, and I was even able to animate it, but I can't get it to trigger these events (show/hide).

"loginField" is another ID I've assigned to a div containing everything in a login popup (email, password, etc).

I'm not sure if I'm just missing knowledge as I'm a noob with all of this.

Thanks!

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Learning to Code</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>

<!-- All header code -->
<div id="header">
<div id="loginIcon">
<img src="LoginIconWhiteForUpload.png" alt="login icon">
</div>
<div id="loginField" alt="login section">
<input type="blank" placeholder="username">
<br>  
<input type="password" placeholder="password">
<center><button type="button" name="button">Log In</button><center>
<br>
Don't have an account?
<br>
<a href="register.html" alt="registration page">Register Now!</a>
</div>
<div id="headerLogo">
<img src="OchoRiosLogoEditedCloud.png" alt="Ocho Rios Logo">
</div>
</div>

<!-- All navication menu code -->
<div id="menu">
<a href="index.html" alt="homepage page link" class="menu, 
menuspacing">HOME</a>
<a href="menu.html" alt="menu page link" class="menu, menuspacing">MENU</a>
<a href="about.html" alt="about page link" class="menu, m 
menuspacing">ABOUT</a>
<a href="contact.html" alt="contact page link" class="menu, m 
menuspacing">CONTACT</a>
</div>

<!-- Main content of the webpage -->
<div class="websiteSection">
<h1>Welcome to Ocho Rios!</h1>
<p>We are so happy you've come to check out our website! We've tried our best 
to put together something presentable.</p>
</div>
<div class="websiteSection">
<h1>Contact us:</h1>
<p> - social media, contact form, etc.
</div>
<div id="footer">
Copywrite © 2020, Ocho Rios Authentic Carribean Cuisine, Calgary, Alberta, 
Canada.
<script type="text/jscript" src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Brian !please post your HTML (or one part of it)

Comment: You have a typo, it's `document` not `documment`

Comment: When working on web page that is not working as expected always check the browser console for errors. The browser console can be opened in most browsers by pressing the F12 key in your keyboard.

Comment: Added the HTML (Pablo)

Comment: Fixed the typo on my end (Luis). And that fixed it!

Comment: Now I feel like an idiot. This is what I get for writing JS at 11PM. Thanks guys! Haha.